# StringBuilder count comma and find position

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I am trying to map two StringBuilders:

```
string builder1 ="abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4,abc2"
string builder2="100,30,15,102,30"
```

both StringBuilders count will be the same and already mapped. But I am searching for a particular number `30` and name like `abc2`

i.e `find(30,abc2)` and remove it

so I need to keep track of the comma or could anyone suggest me best practice to remove the string I don't want in the appropriate position.

Comment: Perhaps use a [**`Regex`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)? -- [**Regular Expressions Language - Quick Reference**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Okay will try to use regex. as i cant use array there is memory constrain.

Comment: It's cute how you think an array will use less memory than a StringBuilder.  ***TEST*** before you make assumptions.

Comment: No its just that there is already a reusable string builder defined. i'll try to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using Regex, it's probably easier to turn the string into a list, remove the items, then recreate the list:

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4,abc2");
string find1 = "abc2";
var newList = sb1.ToString().Split(',').ToList();
newList.RemoveAll(x => x == find1);
string result = string.Join(",", newList.ToArray());
```

For the VB.Net version:

```
Dim sb1 As New StringBuilder("abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4,abc2")
Dim find1 As String = "abc2"
Dim newList As New List(Of String)(sb1.ToString().Split(","c).ToList)
newList.RemoveAll(Function(x) x = find1)
Dim result As String = String.Join(",", newList.ToArray())
```

Comment: is there a way to split or differentiate directly from the string builder. without using a list.

Comment: As any new variable I declare results in out of memory exception

Comment: How big is the string you are dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

So I see 4 cases:

- equals to `"abc2"`  (seems very unlikely)
- contains `",abc2,"`
- starts with `"abc2,"`
- ends with `",abc2"`

---

```
Sub removeCSVvalue(sb As StringBuilder, value$)
    If sb.Length <= value.Length Then sb.Replace(value, vbNullString) : Return ' If sb = value
    sb.Replace("," & value & ",", ",")   ' Example: replace ",abc2," with ","
    Dim C = value.Length
    If sb.Length > C Then If sb(C) = "," Then If sb.ToString(0, C) = value Then sb.Remove(0, C + 1) ' If sb.StartsWith(value & ",")
    Dim L = sb.Length - C
    If sb.Length > C Then If sb(L - 1) = "," Then If sb.ToString(L, C) = value Then sb.Length = L - 1 ' If sb.EndsWith("," & value)
End Sub
```

P.S. this reminds me of my first downvoted answer [Remove item from string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362306/remove-item-from-string-array/11668994#11668994) :]